# Derivative question with series

Tags: calculus

I am having this question here. Find the 66th derivative of $\displaystyle \cos x^3$ Yes, the cube is on the $x$. The idea is to do it with series. 
I got an answer which I want to verify if it is right. Substituting for $x$ the term $x^3$ in the series, I end up with $\displaystyle\frac{x^{6n}}{(2n)!}(-1)^n$ behind the summation, which gives $n=11$ and hence I find as an answer $\displaystyle-\frac{66!}{22!}$ Do you concur?

Comment: I take it you mean the 66th derivative evaluated at $x = 0$?

Comment: @SimonS  Yes, that is what I meant. Is my answer right?

Comment: I checked: it is correct.

Comment: Yes, looks good.

Comment: OK then, I think I know what I am doing! I can prepare the answers for my questions as well. Thanks!!!